# Memory read/write acсess error exception

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

My code is unstable: sometimes everything is fine, and sometimes throws the error memory read/write or _CrtIsValidHeapPointer. When I run the program in 'Release build' it crashes on the second repetition of the actions described in the main () But when its run on 'Debug mode' in 'Release build' with breakpoints on every action - everything works fine even after three iterations of main (). Still havent stability. I do not know - whats wrong with that. Help, please.

P. S. I recreate question post.

Main.cpp

```
int main(...)
{
    // ...
    std::vector<CResource> m_aRes;
    uint8 testBuf[70000];

    m_aRes.push_back(CResource(70000));
    m_aRes.back().SetName("Test Name");
    m_aRes.back().SetType("Test Type");
    m_aRes.back().AppendData(testBuf, 70000);
    // ...
}
```

CResource.h

```
class CResource
{
protected:
    std::string m_sName;    
    std::string m_sSubName; 
    std::string m_sType;

    std::vector<uint8> m_Data;
UINT               m_DataLen;
public:
    CResource(UINT size);
    ~CResource();   

    void          SetName(char * name);
    void          SetType(char * type);
    const char *  GetName(void);
    const char *  GetType(void);
    const char *  GetSubName(void);
    bool          IsWhole(void);
    UINT          AppendData(uint8 * data, UINT len);
    uint8 *       GetData(void);
    UINT          GetDataLen(void);
    UINT          GetDataLenTemp(void);
};
```

CResource.cpp

```
CResource::CResource(UINT size)
{
    m_sName.clear();
    m_sSubName.clear(); 
    m_sType.clear();    

    m_DataLen = size;
    m_Data.reserve(m_DataLen);
}
CResource::~CResource()
{   
    m_sName.clear();
    m_sName.shrink_to_fit();
    m_sSubName.clear();
    m_sSubName.shrink_to_fit();
    m_sType.clear();
    m_sType.shrink_to_fit();    

    m_Data.clear();
    m_Data.shrink_to_fit(); 
}

void CResource::SetName(char * name)
{
    if(!name) return;

    m_sSubName.clear();
    m_sName = name;

    bool bSubNameFound = false;
    for(UINT i=m_sName.size(); i>0; i--) {
            if(bSubNameFound)
                    m_sSubName.insert(0 , &m_sName[i - 1]);
            if(m_sName[i] == '/')
                    bSubNameFound = true;
    }
}
void CResource::SetType(char * type)
{
    if(!type) return;

    m_sType = type;
}
const char * CResource::GetName(void) 
{ 
    return m_sName.c_str(); 
}
const char * CResource::GetType(void)
{ 
    return m_sType.c_str(); 
}
const char * CResource::GetSubName(void) 
{ 
    return m_sSubName.c_str();
}
bool CResource::IsWhole(void) 
{
    return (m_DataLen > 0 && m_DataLen == m_Data.size()) ? true : false; 
}
UINT CResource::AppendData(uint8 * data, UINT len)
{
    if(!data || !len || IsWhole() || m_DataLen == 0) return NULL;   

    UINT DataLenApp = m_Data.size() + len;

    if(DataLenApp > m_DataLen)                   
    {                                               
            len = m_DataLen - m_Data.size();             
            DataLenApp = m_DataLen;                     
    }   

    UINT nFirstApp = m_Data.size();
    for(UINT i = nFirstApp; i < DataLenApp; i++)
                m_Data.push_back(data[i - nFirstApp]);

    return len;
}
uint8 * CResource::GetData(void) 
{ 
    return m_Data.data(); 
}
UINT CResource::GetDataLen(void) 
{
    return m_DataLen; 
}
UINT CResource::GetDataLenTemp(void) 
{ 
    return m_Data.size();
}
```

Comment: That's an awfully big array you are allocating - sometimes 64k bytes is the max you get. There is something about a difference in memory management between debug and "regular" compile modes which may be at play here. I would try `uint8 *testBuf; testBuf = malloc(70000*sizeof(uint8));` for allocating the array and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: In a previous version my CResource classwas bulided with calloc() and realloc(), without vectors and std strings. But problem was appering and now it not disapper. I think std::vector makes this call of malloc or anyone else allocator.

Comment: In `SetName`, you set `i = m_sName.size()` and then do `m_sName[i] == '/'`. You are reading beyond the end of the string when you do this. Other than that, there's really only two places where a problem could occur: `m_sSubName.insert(0 , &m_sName[i - 1]);` and `data[i - nFirstApp]`.

Comment: IT WORKS!!! Thanks to jliv902 and Johan!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried here (g++ 4.8.2 - cygwin) no crash. Check [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20911426/memory-read-write-acess-error-exception/20912120#comment31393398_20911426) for a good suggestion related to your crash.

But, what are you trying to do ?

```
m_DataLen = size;
m_Data.reserve(m_DataLen);
```

`m_DataLen` seems a synonym of [`m_Data.capacity()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity).

Here you're forbidding the reallocation of the array (with the `IsWhole` checking that [`m_Data.size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) is not equal to `m_DataLen`:

```
if(!data || !len || IsWhole() || m_DataLen == 0) return NULL;
```

You should at least simplify your check by avoid this double definition of `m_DataLen` and use `m_Data.capacity()`.

BTW, the following code does not seem wrong, but a lot more complicated than what's needed:

```
UINT nFirstApp = m_Data.size();
for(UINT i = nFirstApp; i < DataLenApp; i++)
   m_Data.push_back(data[i - nFirstApp]);
```

It's basically:

```
m_Data.insert(m_Data.end(), data, data + (DataLenApp - nFirstApp));
```

So my rule of thumb: simplify your code and use what's the STD provides !

Comment: m_Data.capacity() - at fisrt i use it, but had errors when it was changed at random time to null and i recieved wrong DataLen. With other remarks i agreed and very grateful to you! I will change my code. Thanks.

Comment: `capacity()` should not change to null. It will change only if you `reserve()`, if you 'shrink_to_fit()` or if you `push_back()` when `size() == capacity()`.

Comment: I dont know when it changed, but i have some errors, and when i add m_DataLen - errors disappered.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your app under Valgrind - it *really* explains most of typical problems.